# ASP.NET MVC 5: ArgumentNullException MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a MySQL Query with the use of the MySQLDatabase.cs (https://github.com/raquelsa/AspNet.Identity.MySQL) from AspNet.Identity.MySQL but I keep on getting an ArgumentNullException over and over. In debug mode, VS2015 points to ***_database***.

Here is my **Student.cs** which has the said query:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace NETIS.Persistence
{
public class Student : StudentViewModel
{
    private MySQLDatabase _database;

    public Student()
    {

    }

    public Student(MySQLDatabase database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public List<StudentViewModel> GetProfiles()
    {
        List<StudentViewModel> students = new List<StudentViewModel>();
        string commandText = "select * from child_t as c left outer join student_t as s on c.child_id = s.child_id union select * from child_t as c right outer join student_t as s on c.child_id = s.child_id;";
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        try
        {
            var rows = _database.Query(commandText, parameters);
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                StudentViewModel student = (StudentViewModel)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StudentViewModel));
                student.child_id = int.Parse(row["child_id"]);
                student.last_name = row["last_name"];
                student.first_name = row["first_name"];
                student.middle_name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["middle_name"]) ? null : row["middle_name"];
                student.ext_name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["ext_name"]) ? null : row["middle_name"];
                student.sex = row["sex"];
                student.birthdate = DateTime.Parse(row["birthdate"]);
                student.child_room_num_or_building = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["room_num_or_building"]) ? null : row["room_num_or_building"];
                student.child_street = row["street"];
                student.child_purok = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["purok"]) ? null : row["purok"];
                student.child_subdivision = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["subdivision"]) ? null : row["subdivision"];
                student.child_brgy_id = int.Parse(row["brgy_id"]);
                student.child_city_code = row["city_code"];
                student.child_province_code = row["province_code"];
                student.student_id = int.Parse(row["student_id"]);
                student.eccd_start = DateTime.Parse(row["eccd_start"]);
                student.eccd_end = DateTime.Parse(row["eccd_end"]);
                student.elementary_school = string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["elementary_school"]) ? null : row["elementary_school"];
            }
            return students;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            // TODO: Implement system error logs
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Implement system error logs
            return null;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And, this is the **StudentController.cs** that will be using the GetProfiles():

```
namespace NETIS.Controllers
{
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    private NetisEntities db = new NetisEntities();
    private Student student = new Student();

    // GET: Student
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         return View(student.GetProfiles().ToList());
    }
```

The **MYSQLDatabase.cs** is meant to take care of the declaration of **_database** which is meant to be initialized already with the default connection of the **Web.config**.

Here is the **MYSQLDatabase.cs**:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;

namespace AspNet.Identity.MySQL
 {
 /// <summary>
 /// Class that encapsulates a MySQL database connections 
 /// and CRUD operations
 /// </summary>
public class MySQLDatabase : IDisposable
{
    private MySqlConnection _connection;

    /// Default constructor which uses the "DefaultConnection" connectionString
    /// </summary>
    public MySQLDatabase()
        : this("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor which takes the connection string name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionStringName"></param>
    public MySQLDatabase(string connectionStringName)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
        _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a non-query MySQL statement
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandText">The MySQL query to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Optional parameters to pass to the query</param>
    /// <returns>The count of records affected by the MySQL statement</returns>
    public int Execute(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        int result = 0;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(commandText))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Command text cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        try
        {
            EnsureConnectionOpen();
            var command = CreateCommand(commandText, parameters);
            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a MySQL query that returns a single scalar value as the result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandText">The MySQL query to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Optional parameters to pass to the query</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object QueryValue(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        object result = null;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(commandText))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Command text cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        try
        {
            EnsureConnectionOpen();
            var command = CreateCommand(commandText, parameters);
            result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        finally
        {
            EnsureConnectionClosed();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a SQL query that returns a list of rows as the result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandText">The MySQL query to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Parameters to pass to the MySQL query</param>
    /// <returns>A list of a Dictionary of Key, values pairs representing the 
    /// ColumnName and corresponding value</returns>
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Query(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> rows = null;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(commandText))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Command text cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        try
        {
            EnsureConnectionOpen();
            var command = CreateCommand(commandText, parameters);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                rows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        var columnName = reader.GetName(i);
                        var columnValue = reader.IsDBNull(i) ? null : reader.GetString(i);
                        row.Add(columnName, columnValue);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            EnsureConnectionClosed();
        }

        return rows;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a connection if not open
    /// </summary>
    private void EnsureConnectionOpen()
    {
        var retries = 3;
        if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            while (retries >= 0 && _connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _connection.Open();
                retries--;
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes a connection if open
    /// </summary>
    public void EnsureConnectionClosed()
    {
        if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a MySQLCommand with the given parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandText">The MySQL query to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Parameters to pass to the MySQL query</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private MySqlCommand CreateCommand(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        AddParameters(command, parameters);

        return command;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the parameters to a MySQL command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandText">The MySQL query to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Parameters to pass to the MySQL query</param>
    private static void AddParameters(MySqlCommand command, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = param.Key;
            parameter.Value = param.Value ?? DBNull.Value;
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to return query a string value 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandText">The MySQL query to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Parameters to pass to the MySQL query</param>
    /// <returns>The string value resulting from the query</returns>
    public string GetStrValue(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        string value = QueryValue(commandText, parameters) as string;
        return value;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
            _connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the **Stack Trace**:

```
   [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
  ASP._Page_Views_Student_Index_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\Fritz\Documents\NETIS_dev\netis\NETIS\Views\Student\Index.cshtml:50
  System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
  System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
  System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
  System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
  System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
  System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
  System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
  System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
  System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744373
  System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: `private Student student = new Student();`  does not initialize `_database`

Comment: You would need something like this in order to make it work: Private Student student = new Student(new DatabaseObject); If you don't use the constructor with the database parameter and pass the database connection to it, the database object won't be initialized.

Comment: @BarryFranklin I tried such already. However, it still gives the same result. I have browsed yet again on the MYSQLDatabase.cs which is supposed to help the initialization of the Database connection and I saw that the way I declared it was supposed to be correct. But then, it still gives the same NullException.

Comment: @e4c5 However, based on the MYSQLDatabase.cs the initialization of _database should be possible?